# Jquery UI datepicker - Disable dates before today

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my aspx page, I have a textbox that is associated with a datepicker(specified with the cssclass).

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate1" CssClass="datepicker" />
```

This works fine.

But, now I need to disable all the dates prior to today and make this reusable for all other aspx pages.

How can I do this?

Comment: How is the datepicker initialized ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this
     $( function() {
       $( "#txtDate1" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
     } );

minDate option support Multiple types:
1. Date: A date object containing the minimum date.
2. Number: A number of days from today. For example 2 represents two days from today and -1 represents yesterday.
3. String: A string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, and "d" for days. For example, "+1m +7d" represents one month and seven days from today.

reference:
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate